# How does C# interface with Visual Studio to access image files?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, uwp, filesystems, skiasharp

I have images imported into a folder in my Solution and I am using SkiaSharp graphics, but I want to use the images from the folder in my solution to create a bitmap which would then be drawn on my canvas. My question is how do I do this?

My code currently is this:

```cs
21           SKImage image = SKImage.FromEncodedData(@"C:\RPS Sim\Objects\Images\rock.png");
22           SKBitmap bm = SKBitmap.FromImage(image);
23           canvas.DrawBitmap(bm, new SKPoint(posMov.x,posMov.y));
```

When I run this code, I get the following error:

```
System.ArgumentNullException
  HResult=0x80004003
  Message=Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: image
  Source=SkiaSharp
  StackTrace:
   at SkiaSharp.SKBitmap.FromImage(SKImage image)
   at RPS_Sim.Objects.Rock..ctor(Single x, Single y, Single speed, Single size) in C:\RPS Sim\Objects\Rock.cs:line 22
   at RPS_Sim.MainPage..ctor() in C:\RPS Sim\MainPage.xaml.cs:line 33
   at RPS_Sim.App..ctor() in C:\RPS Sim\App.xaml.cs:line 13
   at RPS_Sim.UWP.MainPage..ctor() in C:\RPS Sim\RPS Sim.UWP\MainPage.xaml.cs:line 24
```

I've not been able to find good sources for understanding how Visual Studio and C# access files, so any help is appreciated.

*File paths in my code are accurate, but they have been edited here so as to not hold personal information*

Comment: An absolute path, like the one you've shown here as an example, really ought to work out of the box, assuming the path actually points to a real file.  Like any other file access, the user under which your program is running would need permission to access the file.

Comment: The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/skiasharp.skimage.fromencodeddata?view=skiasharp-2.88#skiasharp-skimage-fromencodeddata(system-string)) for `SKImage.FromEncodedData` states that the method returns `null` on error.  The cause for the error could be anything.  You can eliminate the file path as a source of the problem by calling [File.Exists](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.exists?view=net-7.0).

Comment: @RobertHarvey - File.Exists() returns true, any idea what could cause SKImage.FromEncodedData to return an error otherwise?

Comment: The source code for SKImage is [here](https://github.com/mono/SkiaSharp/blob/main/binding/Binding/SKImage.cs).

Answer (score 0):

First, UWP apps run in a sandbox, and UWP apps are isolated from the system. If you want to get files in a UWP application, you need to use Windows Runtime APIs, such as [Windows.Storage Namespace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.storage?view=winrt-22621). Your behavior is because you are using .net API (`SKImage.FromEncodedData`) to get file by Path, but it is not allowed in UWP app.

Second, UWP applications have some limitations when accessing system resources such as files. By default, UWP apps can access certain locations, such as the application data location. If you want to access other places like the picture gallery, you need to declare a capability in your UWP app's mainfest file or [Open files and folders with a picker](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/files/quickstart-using-file-and-folder-pickers). More info here: [File Access Permissions.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/files/file-access-permissions)

If you really need to access files where UWP apps can't, or you want to get files by path, you need to use the restricted feature - **broadFileSystemAccess**. Add this capability in your app's manifest file and enable it in **Settings > Privacy > Filesystem** after deploying your app.

After getting the file, use the [StorageFile.OpenAsync method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.storage.storagefile.openasync?view=winrt-22621) to get the stream. Then convert the stream to `System.IO.Stream`, and call the result Stream in `SKImage.FromEncodedData` to get the image.